# File Creating Exception on Launching Application

Tags: java, android, file, r.java-file, android-file

I have a test application which has a `ForgroundService` for keeping my app alive , it works fine until i delete the application folder(which created on application startup) , if i force stop the app then relaunch it , the folder has been created successfull with no errors but if i delete the folder without doing force stop , on relaunching app the folder is not created successfully and even it cannot be opened with ESFileExplorer.

I don't know why this happens and how can i prevent this on some situations which user delete folder by a file manager application.

i don't know maybe this line in LogCat cause this issue(there is not any other exception in Logcat):

```
08-02 15:39:04.816: E/InputDispatcher(509): channel '427e97d0 com.estrongs.android.pop/com.estrongs.android.pop.app.PopNoteEditor (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Comment: That message is not useful. Check logcat for other errors.  Check your code for catch blocks which silently absorb failures without printing a stack trace.  It's likely you are only checking for the missing folder and creating it in onCreate(), and your test involved re-entering an already existing Activity after deletion, so onCreate() is not called.  Perhaps you need to check in one of the other lifecycle methods, or simply check each time you intended to use it.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : thank you very much for your comment, i've checked the file structure in onResume() again to remake directory if there is not, there is no error on running application. it just doesn't create directory right when i delete data directory from ExFileExplorer without ForceClosing the app. with force close and relaunch the app, it makes directory successfull. the directory is like a corrupted file in EsFileExplorer.